# How to block users from directly accessing a page, but not HTTP requests in PHP?

Tags: php, http

Before I start, I hope that this question isn't that badly written. My last questions got negative attention due to the sheer ugliness of the question formatting. Either way, here's my question:

I'm making a program where I have to send `GET` requests to my domain to get information and statistics, etc.
Though, my problem is: how would I **efficiently (and in *PHP only*)** stop the typical user/person/cat/etc from accessing my page, and only let HTTP requests in?

Example: I send a `GET` request to `"foo.php"` on my domain from an external program. User knows I'm getting content from the page and tries to visit the page itself directly.

How would I stop the user from seeing the page in their browser directly, but perfectly allow HTTP requests (such as `GET` requests) to fetch my content?

Comment: you had to [dig a little deeper in google](https://perishablepress.com/eight-ways-to-blacklist-with-apaches-mod_rewrite/) - well, it's google first result. try the **Blacklist via the User Agent**. although i personally, if the requests were ajax, check whether it's ajax or not, if not throws error page. however a plain `program` where you send `GET` request is still a broad topic.

Comment: Well, he asked for a php solution so that link won't do much good

Comment: Thank you Tezla for providing me with some research into Apache, and thank you Andy for reminding Tezla that I was looking for PHP-only. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually a browser is also sending a HTTP GET request, so you need a different approach to distinguish between a GET made buy your script/service and one from a browser.

You have a lot of different approaches, here 2 possible solutions:

A) Use a particular user agent when you do your get request. This is the de-facto standard for monitoring services to identify the request.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != "your_user_agent") {
    die();
}
```

B) Use a special token to authorise your request

```
// if you like to send the token as parameter like foo.php?auth=bar
if ($GET['auth'] != "your_token") {
    die();
}

// or use this if you like to send it as a header named auth
if ($_SERVER['auth'] != "your_token") {
    die();
}
```

Comment: Ah. Good approach. I thought of this beforehand but my PHP knowledge isn't that wise so I discarded the solution. Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add a condition in foo.php that checks for the $_GET parameter and then stop at that point.

```
if (!isset($_GET)) {
   die();
} else {
  // Regular programming 
}
```

Of course that doesn't then someone from visiting `foo.php?doesthisvariablework=1`and getting through.

Comment: Testing your solution out as we speak. I'll mark your answer as correct and +1 it if it works. Thanks in advance! :)